# sharepoint dns name not machine name

Tags: workflow

In my workflow I've used the following for a http link to an item in sharepoint

workflowProperties.SiteUrl + ...

which returns http:\machinename\myweb

When people browse they use a domain name http:\sharepoint\myweb NOT the machine name.
I believe there is an A record in IIS that does this routing. However if I was to browse http//machinename in the browser it remains as http//machinename. I want it automatically read http//sharepoint or in my workflow replace machinename to sharepoint.

Thanks

Comment: did my response help Raj?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to "host header" of the web application to which your site collections belong.

have you used `workflowProperties.Site.HostName` property to get the host name?

If you have alternate access mapping being set up, With that in mind, you can use the SPWebApplication's AlternateUrls collection to get the host header(s) associated with that web application.

Since it is possible to have multiple URLs associated with a single web application, you would need to iterate through this collection to get/find the host header you want. For e.g. function below return the URL in default zone.

```
private string LocalWebUrl()
{
    string localUrl = null;
    using (SPWeb web = workflowProperties.Site.RootWeb) {
        using (SPSite site = web.Site) {
            foreach (object altUrl_loopVariable in site.WebApplication.AlternateUrls()) {
                altUrl = altUrl_loopVariable;
                if (altUrl.UrlZone == Administration.SPUrlZone.Default) {
                    localUrl = altUrl.IncomingUrl.ToString;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return localUrl;
}
```